# `get_all_outcomes()`: error when using cuminc

Tags: r

I am trying to do a competing risk analysis in a medical database.

After installing packages I read were needed I run the following code:

`cuminc(Surv(HAPLO$SEGUIMIENTO, HAPLO$SEGFINAL) ~ 1, data = HAPLO`

And I keep getting this error

Error in `get_all_outcomes()`:
! The following outcomes were not found in `data`: 'HAPLO'.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

If i run `rlang::last_trace()`

I get

Backtrace:
▆

1. ├─tidycmprsk::cuminc(...)
2. └─tidycmprsk:::cuminc.formula(...)
3. ├─hardhat::mold(formula, data, blueprint = hardhat::default_formula_blueprint(intercept = TRUE))
4. └─hardhat:::mold.formula(formula, data, blueprint = hardhat::default_formula_blueprint(intercept = TRUE))
5. ```
   ├─hardhat::run_mold(blueprint, data = data)
   ```
6. ```
   └─hardhat:::run_mold.default_formula_blueprint(blueprint, data = data)
   ```
7. ```
     └─hardhat:::mold_formula_default_process(...)
   ```
8. ```
       └─hardhat:::mold_formula_default_process_outcomes(...)
   ```
9. ```
         └─hardhat:::get_all_outcomes(formula, data)
   ```

I dont know what to do.
Thanks in advance.
RAFA

Comment: I think if you are using the formula interface to the function, you should not specify the columns using `$`. Try `cuminc(Surv(SEGUIMIENTO, SEGFINAL) ~ 1, data = HAPLO)`. Also your code is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Great, I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formula interface to a function, you supply just the column names *e.g.* `SEGUIMIENTO`, rather than `HAPLO$SEGUIMIENTO`.

So for data frame `HAPLO` this should work:

```
library(tidycmprsk)

cuminc(Surv(SEGUIMIENTO, SEGFINAL) ~ 1, data = HAPLO)
```